# HTML object element take up space in page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page with a `object` tag. The codebase attribute points to a .cab file. The problem is, in chrome browser the element take up some space and shows an empty space in the browser. This happens in chrome only. Below is the code : https://jsfiddle.net/pv2wjt52/

```
<div class="container">
  <object id="SampleX" codebase="../utils/SampleControl.cab" classid="clsid:58F47D90-DB5D-HK8-B9B5-CHKHH786HJ67">
    <param name="Visible" value="0">
  </object>    
</div>
```

The `SampleX` is used in my javascript to access some properties. Since this is a legacy code I am not completely aware of the intention of this code. If I add a css to make it `display:none;` it will remove the empty space. But will it affect the actual intention of `object` element? Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: `visibility:none; and position:absolute` might help you.

Comment: Don't let these comments and answers fool you. Using those CSS properties does NOT remove them from the DOM. Those are display properties only and have no effect on the DOM which is created before CSS is ever applied.

Comment: @Rob what is your point? If this comment tried to convey the idea that OP could just use `display:none` without any counter-part, then you might want to know that webkit browsers *(for no known-of-myself-good-reasons-but-still-that's-what-they-do...)* do unload `<object>`'s content when they're not diplayed on the page, and yes, this means that they will unload object's with `display:none` rules.

Comment: @Kaiido The point is, he wants to not take space up in the DOM and CSS will not do that. I am aware that he is confusing the DOM with presentation and the CSSOM.

Comment: @Kaiido Which is what I am trying to teach him/them about.

Comment: @Kaiido First the DOM is created. CSS comes later and affects display of elements. CSS does not remove DOM nodes. If one were to remove `display:none` then there would be no element to display.

Comment: @Kaiido, Rob,  Sorry for the confusion in the title. I meant the rendered web page

Comment: @Kaiido Again, setting `display:none` on `<object>` does not remove it from the DOM but I don't have time to do more teaching.

Answer (score 0):

as Jai mentioned you want to use `visibility:hidden` and `position:absolute` the reason is that using `display:none` will simply hide the element from view, where as visibility keeps its occupying space on the page. hope this helps :D

Comment: There is no value `none` for `visibility` property

Comment: Apologies, That should be `hidden`, that's what I get for not looking it up before posting :D